# Need to edit a Kubernetes configration with a shell command

Tags: linux, shell, kubernetes, automation

I want to edit a Kubernetes Ingress configuration and add/replace some data inside the file using a linux command, as i am writing a shell script.

The command i have to use is :

```
kubectl edit svc -n istio-system istio-ingressgateway
```

The command opens up a VI editor and i need to replace some lines to achieve my setup, and i want to write a shell command that opens up, appends and saves into it.

Answer (score 4):

you can use the [kubectl patch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/).

if there is a simple change, for example, change patching `loadBalancerIP`

```
kubectl patch services itom-cdf-ingress-frontend-svc -p '{"spec":{"type":"LoadBalancer","loadBalancerIP": "EXTERNAL-IP"}}' -n core
```

if there are some nested or complex changes, you can use also `JSON` file as well.

[kubectl_patch-json](https://jamesdefabia.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_patch/)

Answer (score -1):

I assume that you want to change the image name in yaml file.

You can use the "sed" command

```
sed 's/old_text/new_text/g' /path/to/file.yaml
```

This is the way if you are using the shell script. But if you are using any programming language you can also parse the yaml file like json.

Comment: i want to use the command : kubectl edit svc -n istio-system istio-ingressgateway, use a pipe and replace a metadata line, and then want to save the configration.
all with one shell command.

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes you can pipe the output of kubectl edit command into the sed. This is the helpful link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sed-command-in-linux-unix-with-examples/

Comment: The command i am using is : kubectl edit svc -n istio-system istio-ingressgateway | sed '9 cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"default": "iap-backendconfig"}''

Error i get is : sed: 1: 
"9 cloud.google.com/back ...": command c expects \ followed by text
Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal

Comment: In this case you have to edit the yaml file and update the object with kubectl apply. If you do not have the yaml file available where you are running the command you can generate one using "kubectl get svc service_name" -o yaml | sed s/old_text/new/g > temp.yaml". Then apply that yaml file.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to pipe the output of `kubectl` edit to sed because it does not output the yaml... the `edit` command downloads the manifest and opens locally in an editor.